# How to View the Entire Contents of a dat File

Tags: files, binary, file-type

I have a dat file that appears to be an application/octet stream binary coded file, which I will like to view. I have tried to use a number of text editors to open the file but none of them opened the file fully and correctly - there were parts that were not decoded, so they appeared corrupted. Is there anyway I can decode this file? I have attached a screenshot of what I got after trying to open the file to this explanation

Answer (score 2):

Since you know its binary, I assume you understand HEX.
If so, you can "dump" the file with "od -xc filename".

If you are familiar with the "vi" editor, then you could use 
a "binary vi editor", called "bvi".

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I am not familiar with anything, so I will appreciate a step-by-step method on how to go about it.

Comment: If you do not understand HEX notation, then what value would you get from seeing the non-printable data in that binary file?  As for "step by step"... using the "od" command was shown... from the command line, enter "od -xc " followed by the name of the file.  You can get more details of the "od" command by reading its man page (run "man od" from command line).  using the "-xc argument will cause "od" to dump both the HEX format of each byte as well as the "character" format of each byte (assuming it is printable) in the file.

Comment: Okay. Would this method make it possible for me to view the content in a text format? All I want it to make the content readable.